# Getting Null CallableStatement with Mockito

Tags: junit, mockito

Hi Actually I have implemented the `CallableStatementCreator` which is callback for jdbc template I am trying to mock its method but getting the `CallableStatement object as null` in try resource below is my code could you please let me know why i am getting null.

**Note if I pass Mockito.anyString() its working but i don't want because spot bugs is throwing below error**

**Bug type SQL_INJECTION_JDBC (click for details)**
**ODR_OPEN_DATABASE_RESOURCE**

```java
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressFBWarnings;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.CallableStatementCreator;

public class TimeEventWarmStoreCallableStatement implements CallableStatementCreator {
  @Override
  @SuppressFBWarnings(value="RCN_REDUNDANT_NULLCHECK_WOULD_HAVE_BEEN_A_NPE",justification = "try with resource false positive issue with java 11")
  public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    try (CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call Employee.CHANGE_TO_WARM_STORE(?,?)}")) {
      cs.setInt(1, 2);
      cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
      return cs;
    }
  }
}
```

Mock Class

```java
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TimEventWarmStoreCallableStatementTest {
  @InjectMocks
  private TimeEventWarmStoreCallableStatement cut;

  @Mock
  private Connection con;

  @Mock
  private CallableStatement callableStatement;

  @BeforeMethod
  public void setup() {
    cut = Mockito.spy(new TimeEventWarmStoreCallableStatement());
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);

  }

  @Test
  public void createCallableStatementTest() throws SQLException {
    doReturn(callableStatement).when(con).prepareCall("{call Employee.CHANGE_TO_WARM_STORE(?,?)}");
    CallableStatement cst = cut.createCallableStatement(con);
    assertNotNull(cst);
  }
}
```

Comment: The test passes for me. I suspect something silly like non-breaking space. (Note: `@InjectMocks` for `TimeEventWarmStoreCallableStatement cut` is a bit misleading, as you are initializing it before `openMocks` call, but this is not the reason for the NPE)

Comment: @Lesiak can you please tell me if how do i write mock test case for callback written inside call not getting how do i cover lines for callback
 return jdbcTemplate.call(con -> {
      CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call Employee.CHANGE_TO_WARM_STORE(?,?)}");
      cs.setInt(1, maxPartition);
      cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
      return cs;
    }, parameters)